# How to define a delayed function with 'If' condition?

Tags: function-construction, conditional

Let us define a function `f[x_]:=x^2`, then I want to define a delayed function `g[x_]` such that

`g[x_]:=f[x]`  `If[f[x]<10]` and

`g[x_]:=0` `If[f[x]>0]`

How can I do that?

Comment: `g[x_]:=Piecewise[{{x^2,x^2<=10}}]`?

Comment: Your condition does not make sense. Look at Piecewise []

Comment: Yes..it works.Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Piecewise`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html):

```
g1[x_] := Piecewise[{{x^2, x^2 <= 10}}]
```

or

```
g2[x_] := If[x^2 <= 10, x^2, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`Condition`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Condition.html):

```
g[x_] := Module[{res = f[x]}, res /; res < 10]
g[x_] := 0
```